# (Python) Complete noobie to coding, just trying out some simple code that I wanted to say one thing if you say good, and another line if u say no

Tags: python

I want the code to say one thing if you type in good, and another if you type in bad. Please don't bully me this is my first hour of coding lol. Its putting out both text strings no matter what I answer, good, bad, my name, any text

```
name = input("Enter your name please: ")

print("hi " + name + " how are you doing?")

Answer = input("Good or bad?")

if Answer : "Good"

print("That's great to hear!")

if Answer : "Bad" 

print("That sucks, why?")
```

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or a similar tutorial if not done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to the world of coding.  You are using the if else syntax wrong. It looks like

```
if condition:
  Some code
else if condition:
  Some code
else
  Some code
```

How a condition looks like is

```
firstValue comparing operator(==(Equals),!=(Not equals),>,<,>=,=< and more) second value
```

So in your case,

```
  name = input("Enter your name please: ")

    print("hi " + name + " how are you doing?")

    Answer = input("Good or bad?")

    if Answer == "Good":# Answer is the first value, == is the operator, "Good" is the second operator

        print("That's great to hear!")

    if Answer == "Bad" :# Answer is the first value, == is the operator, "Bad" is the second operator

        print("That sucks, why?")
```

I hope you understand this. Ways you can make improvements (Don't pay attention if you do not understand)\

1> If we convert answer into lowercase, the user can write Good, gOod, good etc. and you will always be able to check it. You do this by using the lower(), method. Call it like this
`lower(String)`
For your code

```
  name = input("Enter your name please: ")

    print("hi " + name + " how are you doing?")

    Answer = lower(input("Good or bad?"))# Convert into lowercase

    if Answer == "good":

        print("That's great to hear!")

    if Answer == "bad" :

        print("That sucks, why?")
```

2> Ok this may seem very complicated, but if you understand it, its very very helpful. What we do is keep asking the user the question till they give the correct answer. It will help us deal with the situation where user writes something we do not want
How we do this is by running a while loop. What it does is keep running until a certain condition becomes false. There are 2 ways we can use it for this program.

**WAY 1**

```
  name = input("Enter your name please: ")
    repeat = True # Defining a condition
    print("hi " + name + " how are you doing?")

    Answer = lower(input("Good or bad?"))# Convert into lowercase
    while repeat: #Saying to the code to run till we have a good result
     if Answer == "good":
        print("That's great to hear!")
        repeat = False #Doing this will make the condition false, which causes us to break this loop and move out

     if Answer == "bad" :
        print("That sucks, why?") 
        repeat = False #Doing this will make the condition false, which causes us to break this loop and move out
     Answer = input("Please give valid input. Good or Bad")
    #Add your remaining code here. please check the indentations
```

**WAY 2**
In this, we dont define a new repeat variable. We use a special command called break

```
  name = input("Enter your name please: ")

    print("hi " + name + " how are you doing?")

    Answer = lower(input("Good or bad?"))# Convert into lowercase
    while True:# Making a loop which is always true
     if Answer == "good":
        print("That's great to hear!")
        break #Breaking out of the loop
     if Answer == "bad" :
        print("That sucks, why?") 
        break #Breaking out of the loop
      Answer = lower(input("Please give valid input. Good or Bad"))
    #Add your code after this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code too, it is using python def, please note indentation plays very important role python and if code is not indented properly it won't behave properly. You can read more about [Python indentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp). I would recommend to look at [W3schools python tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp), they not only provide lots of examples but also provide interactive shell where you can try out the code.

```
def greeting(greet):
    if greet == "Good":
        print("That's great to hear!")
    if greet == "Bad":
        print("That sucks, why?")
        
name = input("Enter your name please: ")
print("hi " + name + " how are you doing?")
Answer = input("Good or bad?")
greeting(Answer)
```